# Interact with all elements in a list in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, lapply, rselenium

I'm trying to interact with all elements of the list in R.
Precisely, I'm trying to click on all elements in list using RSelenium using clickElement() function.
I'm scraping data from this webpage: 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=hr.mireo.arthur&hl=en&fbclid=IwAR3c-PkUXOea8KrKLp9Q3JUjCidGmgO2jYX_Qb7O8VuWlHXPIS5nDOfKRKI&showAllReviews=true

Here is my code so far:

```
    url <- 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=hr.mireo.arthur&hl=en&fbclid=IwAR3c-PkUXOea8KrKLp9Q3JUjCidGmgO2jYX_Qb7O8VuWlHXPIS5nDOfKRKI&showAllReviews=true'
#Open webpage using RSelenium
    rD <- rsDriver(port = 4445L, browser=c("chrome"), chromever="80.0.3987.106")
    remDr <- rD[["client"]]
    remDr$navigate(url)
    #-----------------------------------------Load whole page by scrolling and showing more
    xp_show_more <- "//*[@id='fcxH9b']/div[4]/c-wiz/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div"
    replicate(5,
              {
                replicate(5,
                          {
                            # scroll down
                            webElem <- remDr$findElement("css", "body")
                            webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "end"))
                            # wait
                            Sys.sleep(1)
                          })
                # find button
                morereviews <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', xp_show_more)
                # click button
                tryCatch(morereviews$clickElement(),error=function(e){print(e)}) # trycatch to prevent any error from stopping the loop
                # wait
                Sys.sleep(3)
              })
```

This code will load the whole page and show all comments, but some comments are long and have the "Full review" buttons which have to be clicked in order to show the whole lenght of the comment. I have managed to find all of those buttons (there are 36 of them) using the "findElements" function withfollowing code:

```
fullreviews <- remDr$findElements(using = 'css selector', value = ".OzU4dc")
```

This code results in a list of 36 elements and when I want to click on them using this code:

```
fullreviews$clickElement()
```

I get the this error:
Error: attempt to apply non-function

I can click on all 36 elements using this 36 lines of code:

```
fullreviews[[1]]$clickElement()
fullreviews[[2]]$clickElement()
fullreviews[[3]]$clickElement()
```

...ans so on until 36.

But I would like to make this possible with one function. In case I have to scrape some bigger webpage and have thousands of elements to click.

I have tried this code, but it doesn't work

```
fullreviews[[1:36]]$clickElement()
```

I guess some sort of lapply function is needed, but I can't manage to creat one which is working.
Is there a way to do this in a single loop or function?

Comment: Can't you just do `lapply(fullreviews, function(x) x$clickElement())`?

Comment: Solution was so simple. Thank you for the quick reply.